# Entity Framework - Changetracker contains to many items

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, change-tracking

I have a C# application which uses Entity Framework 6.
I query a database like this:

```
public static DB.Core.DBBlob getBlob(DB.Core.DBAspect aspect, int index)
    {
        var blobs = aspect.DBBlobs.Where(b => b.Index == index);
        return blobs.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The problem is now that the changetracker contains 2 entries
[image]

The first item is the one I queried from the database and the second one is the one I excluded with the where statement (I only want to have the item with Index == 1).

It seems that EF6 is loading both entries from database and adding to the changetracker.

I tried already setting following settings:

```
dbm.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
dbm.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
dbm.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Hopefully somebody is able to help me.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you afraid of performance problems? Are you sure, that the entities values are loaded or are they perhaps loaded when you debug and access them?

Comment: The problem is that the entity framework loads the data from the database and the memory increases. The performance goes down as well.

Comment: Are you really sure about that or are that assumptions? If it was like you say, that would be a **huge** problem and EF wouldn't be usable at all if tables get bigger.

Comment: Yes I´m pretty sure. When I remove all entries from changetracker with index == 2 the memory is not increasing (of course it increases by the items with index == 1).

Comment: What is `DBAspect`? Also `aspect.DBBlobs`?

Comment: Both items are DbSet´s
    public virtual DbSet<DBAspect> DBAspects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DBBlob> DBBlobs { get; set; }

DBAspect has a List of DBBlobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
The problem is that Entity Framework is loading all "child" elements.
What I do now is that I query the DbSet directly (taking the database model) and add in the where statement the Id of the parent item.